# Is there a way to stop approval emails being sent in Salesforce?

Tags: salesforce

The user does not want to receive the approval emails in Salesforce. Is there a way to stop these emails?

Comment: Don't forget to click the check mark next to the best answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit user and switch `Receive Approval Request Emails` to `Never`